# Power Automate Flow reads excel and sends to Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, power-automate, rpa, power-automate-custom-connector

I have an excel file stored in SharePoint site. And I have an Azure Function written in Python deployed in Azure.

My task is to create a Power Automate Flow which allows the user to read the excel file first, then the Flow will somehow send the data from excel to my Azure function for processing and return the output back. Now I am stuck at reading the excel and sending it to my Azure. Any suggestions on how to implement this? Note that I cannot read from SharePoint directly in Python due to authentication restrictions.

Edit:
So far, my attempt for this task can be seen in this Power Automate Flow .[image: Flow example]

where **Get file content using path** is reading the excel sheets from sharepoint site;

**Initialize variable** just creates a temp file name which will be used in creating blob in Azure blob storage;

**Create blob (v2)** is to copy the file content and create the blob in Azure blob storage;

In **Http2**, a POST request will be sent to my Azure Function (written in Python) where all the complex data processing is performed. *I am stuck here* - how should I read the data back to Flow and use the values in the data table to send emails? I could not find an **Action** that can directly read table from blob. So I was trying to get file content (the processed data) from blob and generate excel file in sharepoint and read the table from there. However, this does not work because in flow, I can only get the so-called **dynamic content**(e.g., the columns of the table) if the file is already there (sharepoint) when I create the flow. Now my question is whether there is a better way to read the data table and be able to parse the columns so I can send emails in the flow.

Comment: You really need to show an attempt here, i.e. what have you tried so far?  Can you update your question so you have a specific issue because as of right now, you're asking someone to architect the solution for you and that's not the purpose of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Skin thanks I have edited the question with my latest attempt. I think I am now left with figuring out how to read data tables from Azure blob storage account.

Comment: Have you looked at OfficeScripts? This may help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466547/power-automate-how-to-extract-hyperlink-from-excel-formula