# Power Automate | How to extract hyperlink from Excel formula?

Tags: excel, power-automate

Ho to extract hyperlink address from Excel worksheet using Power Automate?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OfficeScripts to achieve it.

Go to Excel and the **Automate** tab in the ribbon.  From here, you can create a script that will take a cell reference as a parameter.  With that cell reference, read the cell and split up the formula.

Call it "**Get Hyperlink From Formula**" (or whatever) and copy this formula in ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, fqCellAddress: string)
{
  const worksheetName = fqCellAddress.split("!")[0];
  const cellAddress = fqCellAddress.split("!")[1];

  let cell = workbook.getWorksheet(worksheetName).getRange(cellAddress);
  let hyperlinkFormula = cell.getFormulaLocal();
  let hyperlink = hyperlinkFormula.split(",")[0].split("(")[1];

  return hyperlink;
}
```

From there, call it from the PowerAutomate action as shown below.

[image: Office Script]

Then in your flow, you'll see the output which you can then work with as required.

**Action**

[image: Action]

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Great idea, thanks a lot for this one 

Comment: Nice solution! I've learned something today.